# R woebin_plot subtitle or text or caption

Tags: r

Is there a way to make “subtitle” (not title) in woebin_plot function?

woebin_plot()

I want to write some notes to the graph screen.

Thanks!!

Comment: You should start by telling us where this function is coming from.

Comment: scorecard R package